# python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-cli, docker-volume

I have Jenkins docker compose and I attempting to mapping my az-cli volume to the container.
Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    jenkins:
        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
        volumes:
            - vol_jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
            - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
            - '/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker'
            - '/usr/bin/docker-compose:/usr/bin/docker-compose'
            - '/usr/bin/az:/usr/bin/az'
            - '/usr/bin/python3.6:/usr/bin/python3.6'
        container_name: jenkins-local
        restart: always
        image: 'jenkins/jenkins:latest'
        networks:
          - docker-net

volumes:
    vol_jenkins:
        external: true 

networks:
    docker-net:
        external: 
            name: docker-net
```

After I apply the docker compose, exec to the container, and type az -v to check the azure-cli version, I got the following error message:
`# python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

My OS is Centos 7, and the target container is Debian.

Is something I missing in configuring the docker compose? Or I have to include mapping all the library of my python3 to the container?

I've already tried to add environments to the docker compose like this:

```
        environment:
          - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
          - PYTHONPATH="$bin_dir/../lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/lib/python3.6/site-packages:/lib64/python3.6"
```

And I hope that will fix the problem, but another issue is appear. It said:

```
/usr/bin/az: line 5: 54 Aborted (core dumped) AZ_INSTALLER=RPM PYTHONPATH="$bin_dir/../lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages" $python_cmd -sm azure.cli "$@"
```

What's causing the problem?

Comment: In general you won't be successful bind-mounting arbitrary host binaries into a container like that.  Can you build a custom Dockerfile that starts `FROM jenkins/jenkins`, and then uses the OS package manager (probably `apt-get`) to install the Docker CLI and other dependencies?  Can you set up your pipelines to run builds in containers, instead of installing Python directly on the worker nodes?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the response. I get it now. I tried to create custom Dockerfile `FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest` and add command to install azure cli base on targeted OS (Jenkins use debian) and it's working, no more issue as I above mentioned. Thank you so much!